# Group by and order by range of age in MySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I have this query that display the age range and the total  without problem:

```
$sql="SELECT 
CASE WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(date_nacer_format, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(date_nacer_format, '00-%m-%d'))) < 1 THEN '< 1 año'
WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(date_nacer_format, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(date_nacer_format, '00-%m-%d'))) <= 4 THEN '1-4 año'
WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(date_nacer_format, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(date_nacer_format, '00-%m-%d'))) <= 14 THEN '5-14 año'

END AS age,
COUNT(*) total
FROM patients_appointments
GROUP BY age";
$data['query']= $this->db->query($sql);
```

In  phpMyAdmin the table displays the data ordered by age as the query is.

But when I display this table with php using codeigniter the table is not ordered by age.

How can I solve this issue ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe modify the SQL text to replace `ORDER BY total ASC` with `ORDER BY age = '< 1 año' DESC, age ASC`

Comment: In your code `ORDER BY total ASC`.  So how do you expect to order itself by `age`?

Comment: Eric your are right my mistake to put ORDER BY total ASC.

Comment: ORDER BY age = '< 1 año' DESC, age ASC : Still not working, the ordering has a good start but it disorders in list below

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '%Y') -
        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '00-%m-%d')))
        <= 14 THEN '0-14'
    WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '%Y') -
        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '00-%m-%d')))
        <= 17 THEN '14-17'
    WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '%Y') -
        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '00-%m-%d')))
        <= 24 THEN '17-24'
    WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '%Y') -
        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '00-%m-%d')))
        <= 34 THEN '25-34'
    WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '%Y') -
        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '00-%m-%d')))
        <= 44 THEN '35-44'
    WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '%Y') -
        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '00-%m-%d')))
        <= 54 THEN '45-54'
    WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '%Y') -
        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '00-%m-%d')))
        <= 64 THEN '55-64'
    WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '%Y') -
        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(u.fecha_nac, '00-%m-%d')))
        <= 122 THEN '65+' END AS edad,
COUNT(*) total
FROM usuario u
GROUP BY edad
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.